# Cast and substring the Date time column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, casting, substring

I have a column `OFFSTARTIME` with a `datetime` datatype. Currently data is appearing as

```
1900-01-01 08:00:00.000
```

I want to show only

```
08:00:00
```

For that I have tried the following query:

```
SUBSTRING(CAST(OFFSTARTIME AS VARCHAR(19)), 12, 19)
```

but it's showing an output of

```
0 8:00AM
```

Answer (score 2):

There is datatype for time only, it's `time` datatype :)

Try `cast(offstarttime as time)`.

If you really want to cast, then cast it to varchar and use `right` function:
`right(cast(offstarttime as varchar(23)), 12)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert value to varchar to get requested output as below. check other [formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx) as well

```
DECLARE @myTime Datetime='1900-01-01 08:00:00.000'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @myTime, 108)
```